# Algebraic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I mean if we change interval of "x" to:

$k>1$ and $x\in(\sqrt[3]{k},\sqrt[5]{k^3})$. 
Define the $B(x)$ as a polynomial as follows;

$B(x)=-2x^7-3x^6k+2k^2x^4-k^3x^3+2k^3x^2+3xk^4-2xk^3+k^4$

I want to check that whether $B(x)$ is positive?
if not, for which values of $k$ it is positive?

Do we have to repeat the method separately for:

$$ y:=\sqrt[3]k $$

then plot B(x,y) and find "y"

and also by defining

$$ z:=\sqrt[5]{k^3} $$

and plot B(x,z)
and find "z"?

And finally finding intersection of the solution in terms of "k?"

Comment: Where is this problem coming from ?

Comment: It's an ODE problem for finding invariant curve.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y:=\sqrt[3]k$ and solve the equation

$$x^7+3x^6-2x^5-\left(y^3+1\right)x^4+\left(2y^3-3\right)x^2+1=0.$$

We easily draw

$$y=\sqrt[3]{\frac{x^7+3x^6-2x^5-x^4-3x^2+1}{x^4-2x^2}}$$ which is the zero set.

That curve is asymptotic to $x=y$ and $x=\sqrt2$, and there are two roots which satisfy $1<x<y$ for every value of $y$ above the minimum. The minimum is obtained by canceling the derivative, which amounts to $$3x^9+6x^8-12x^7-24x^6+12x^5+10x^4-4x^2+4=0.$$

We have one root $x\approx1.77368776,y\approx2.97774722$, then $k\approx26.4036205$.

There is also the isolated solution $x=1,y=1,k=1$.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I'm a little bit confused. Because I don't know what did you do to show that B(x) is positive !

Comment: It would be really appreciated if you could send me the Code of this figure.

Comment: @MaryamAmini: code ?? This was not programmed.

Comment: so how did you do this picture? Because I need it to analyze my other problems

Comment: @MaryamAmini: this is done with Microsoft Mathematics, a high quality freeware.

Comment: Thanks. I did it with your preferred freeware, and it's really cool.

Comment: Question???  ; How we can do this strategy for "B(x)" if; x\in(\sqrt[3]{k},\sqrt[5]{k^3})

Comment: @MaryamAmini: plot the curve of $x=\sqrt5k^3$, which is $x=\sqrt5 y^9$.

Comment: How you found it?

Comment: I think they should be "k=x^3" and "k=x^(5/3)"

Comment: Is it right? If yes, then do I have to plot B(x) for "k=x^3" and "k=x^(5/3)" separately and then find an intersection of the solutions?

Comment: @MaryamAmini: yep that's an option.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding of my question of change of interval of "x". because of that I have edited my question, So you can find it on the top

Comment: @MaryamAmini: don't silently change a question. This makes existing comments/questions inappropriate.

Comment: Yes, it was my fault. And forgot it

Answer (score -1):

**Edit: As pointed out in the discussion wrong region for minimization was taken. Following plots display minima of $B(x)$ on $0<x<k^{1/3}$ which is not what the problems is concerned with.**

It turns out that for small values of $k$ $B(x)$ is not always positive. For very large values of $k$ again minimum of $B(x)$ becomes negative (qualitatively for moderate values of $x$ term $-k x^4$ eventually dominates as $k$ gets large enough).

There is a range of values of $k$ for which $B$ is positive. I couldn't find any simple expression for the boundaries of this region but it's approximately $1.245 < k <26.4$

Some illustrative plots below

[[image: small values of <span class=]$k$">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23TAu.png)
[[image: large values of <span class=]$k$">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Glx3.png)

Comment: Thank you so much for your great help. But I did not understand how you plotted without using of x variable?      How you plotted for min(B(x))?

Comment: Did you do these pictures in Maple?

Comment: Pictures are done in Mathematica. Vertical axis is minimum of $B(x)$ over all values of x allowed for given value of $K$

Comment: Can I have access to the Mathematica code ?

Comment: Use NMinimize with appropriate constraints, I haven't saved this - it was like a single line.

Comment: $B$ remains positive down to $k=1$. Your value $k=1.245$ (IMO $k=1.2409160461914$) corresponds to the root $x=0.88950529$, which is out of range.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Oh, I see what happened, I've missed the condition of $x>1$ and was minimizing on $0<x<k^{1/3}$. You are correct this is my mistake.

Comment: Question??? ; How we can do this strategy for "B(x)" if; x\in(\sqrt[3]{k},\sqrt[5]{k^3})